# Doctrine not doing update

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, flush

I'm working on a PHP project that uses Doctrine.  The problem is that updates to an entity are not going through, ie the DB isn't being updated.  The code looks like this:

```
// findOrGetUser does the lookup for the entity, and will create it if 
// it isn't found.  $userAccount is a Doctrine entity
$userAccount = findOrGetUser($user);

// setAuthTok is a member function of User, defined in DataObjs.php, 
// that sets a property of User
$userAccount->setAuthTok("hello");

$em->flush();
```

What happens is, if the entity doesn't exist in the DB, a record will be created and authTok will be set to "hello".  If it doesn't, it will keep its previous value (a 212 digit number).  So the update will go through on a newly created record, but not in an update scenario.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

The DB is MySQL, I tried both the mysqli and pdomysql drivers and they both did the same thing.  I tried adding a persist() call before the flush, but that made no difference.

I tried adding explicit transaction handling, and I also had a look at the Doctrine source code and traced it through as far as I could, and couldn't find anything wrong.

EDITS - I forgot to mention that this code works OK on the test server.  So it would seem the problem is some kind of configuration error?

Here is the code I used when trying explicit transaction handling:

```
try {
    $em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
    $userAccount = findOrGetUser($user);
    $userAccount->setAuthTok("hello");
    $em->persist($userAccount);
    $em->flush();
    $em->getConnection()->commit();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    fileLog("(" . $ex->getFile() . " " . $ex->getLine() . ") " .$ex->getMessage());
    $em->getConnection()->rollback();
    $em->close();
    throw $e;
}
```

Comment: Just throwing this out there, but shouldnt you `$userAccount->persist()` first?

Answer (score 0):

I realize you said you've tried adding a call to persist() before the flush but you don't say how you call so I'll answer this anyway:
You need to call $em->persist($userAccount); before the flush, otherwise the entity manager has nothing to write to the database.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've added above some more code that I tried, which includes the call that you suggested.

Comment: Based on the extra information: is the production server using some caching like memcached or similar?